# Laravel delete button throwing out error "page couldn't be found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

this is my code

view

```
<form action="/categories/ {{ $category->id }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

    <button>Delete Task</button>
</form>
```

controller method

```
public function destroyCategory($id)
{

    Categories::findOrFail($id)->delete();

    return redirect('/categories');
}
```

route

```
Route::post('categories','FilesController@destroyCategory');
```

Form is in partial view, can that be a problem

Comment: You have a space in your form's action attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You send `DELETE` method from your form but you catch it as a `post` instead of `delete` inside your `route` file & also you not assign `URL` parameter in your `route` file.

```
<form action="/categories/{{ $category->id }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

    <button type="submit">Delete Task</button>
</form>
```

**route.php**

```
Route::delete('categories/{id}','FilesController@destroyCategory');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have space after `/categories` and you don't use submit button:

```
<form action="/categories/{{ $category->id }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
    <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete Task">
</form>
```

Or with Laravel Collective forms:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'Delete', 'route' => ['task.delete', $category->id]) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Delete Task')  !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Also, you're using `post` route instead of `delete`. And, as @Rimon Khan said, you do not catch ID of a category:

```
Route::delete('categories/{id}', ['as' => 'task.delete', 'uses' => 'FilesController@destroyCategory']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

Your Routes should be like:

```
Route::post('categories/{id}','FilesController@destroyCategory')->name('delete_categories');
```

Your Controller should be like:

```
public function destroyCategory($id)
{
  Categories::findOrFail($id)->delete();
  return redirect()->to('/');
}
```

and HTML would be like this:

```
<form action="{{ route('delete_categories', ['id' => $category->id]) }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

    <button type="submit">Delete Task</button>
</form>
```

Hope this helps